# Using RTL languages with MS Office in Wine 1.4

Tags: wine, microsoft-office, hebrew, microsoft-word, rtl

I've installed MS Office 2007 in Ubuntu 12.04 using Wine 1.4 with no problems, and it works fine with the English Language.  However, I need to use it to work with Arabic and Hebrew, and it doesn't work when I switch to a Hebrew or Arabic keyboard.  The typing gets reversed.

I saw an earlier post for something similar, but it is closed and I think it was for the earlier Wine 1.3.  Supposedly Wine 1.4 has added RTL -- is there a way to get it working?

Comment: 16/3/2015 still no solution

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, you can use usp10.dll to make RTL fonts to display properly. This dll can be downloaded via winetricks. Also, if you install office using PlayOnLinux, this dll will be included by default.

If you want to make the RTL and LTR icons appear in office programs, you should first install Arabic, Herbew, ... language pack in Ubuntu, then you can run wine with proper LANG environment. For instance:

```
LANG=en_us.utf-8 wine /path/to/office/executable
```

replace en_us.utf-8 with your desired language.

Comment: yes! usp10 does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Open up winetricks, "select the default wine prefix", "Install a Windows DLL...", `usp10` and OK.

After it finishes installation, open up "configure wine" (wineconfig), "Libraries" tab, "New overrride for library" (the drop-down menu), usp10, Add, now you should see it in the list below (Existing_overrides), select it and click "Edit", set it to "Native" and OK.

That's it. Languages should display correctly now.

I'm not sure if the last step is necessary but do it anyways. (The one where we set the library to native)